# Display new form field after user select something in select field

Tags: php, symfony

I have made a simple form with Symfony form type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();
    $domainsNamesTransformer = new DomainsNamesTransformer();

    $builder->add(
        $builder->create('domains', TextareaType::class, [
            'label' => 'form.names',
            'translation_domain' => 'global',
            'constraints' => [
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
            ],
        ])
        ->addModelTransformer($domainsNamesTransformer)
    );

    // Limit to user servers
    $builder->add('server', EntityServerType::class, [
        'user' => $options['user'],
        'nadmin_compliant' => true,
        'ip_network' => IpV4::NETWORK_PUBLIC,
        'required' => true,
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\NotBlank(),
        ],
    ]);

    // Ask if user want a database
    $askDatabase = function (FormInterface $form, $server) {
        if ($server != null && $server->getMysqlServer === true) {
            $form->add('database', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'domain.form.associated_databases',
                'translation_domain' => 'front',
                'required' => false,
            ]);
        }
    };
}
```

I'm trying to display a new field when the user select an option in the `server` field.
So I have made a `eventListener` to do this but when I select an option, nothing append...

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($askDatabase) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if (array_key_exists('server', $data)) {
            $askDatabase($form, $data['server']);
        }
    });
```

I also tried with `POST_SET_DATA` and `PRE_SUBMIT` but nothing append anyway.

**EDIT**

The array key `server` exist inside `$data` because when I dump it, I get `null` at the loading of the page.

Is this doable with `eventListener` or this is the wrong way to do this ?
How can I do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you want to add adtional field? 

When user edit this data, or when user add new entity?

Comment: The `server` field is a select one with a list of servers, so when the user select one server in this list, the new field is added.

Comment: This will only be possible if you transfer (after the user has selected something) the whole serialized form via ajax to a controller action and let the controller-action manipulate the form, then you will have to transfer the form back via json and replace your old form with the updated one